# Why I've set up a prototype cell but nothing showed up?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

```
class DemoTableController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var answerView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    answerView.delegate = self
    answerView.dataSource = self
    answerView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.

    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 5
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

I add the tableView to a view in a ViewController via StoryBoard.

And then I add a button to my prototype cell. The blank tableView does show up , but it's without the button.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should use Auto Layout explained [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this line,your code should work.Here you do not need `registerClass`

```
 answerView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

Comment: If you use custom class of tableview cell,you may need to register.If you use default `UITableviewCell`,you do not need to register

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure you correctly set your identifier within your storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

It has to be the same that in your line below :

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

*Also, you probably won't need to use the `registerClass` method on your tableView (in your viewDidLoad).*

Comment: Yes. Deleting the registerClass worked. But why? Thank you guys you are so helpful.

Comment: There is no need of it when working directly within the prototype cell (and without a custom cell class/nib). If the cell class was written in code you have to register it (in order to reuse it) using the registerClass: method otherwise with the registerNib: method if the cell was created through a nib file.